PySide/PyQT GeoJSON load and reload using Folium
I'm developing an application with PySide6 that visualize a GeoJSON over OSM, using Folium. Basically, I select a geojson from file, it shows in the map (into a pyqt window), and I should be able to select features in the geojson and do something with them (ie dynamically color some features if they are in a set that can vary at run time). This is the code of the widget for visualising the map.

import json
import os
import folium

from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QObject, Signal
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QSizePolicy
from branca.element import Element, JavascriptLink

class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    net_handler = None
    on_map_clicked = Signal(float, float, int)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
    
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, line, sourceID):
        print(msg)  # Check js errors
        if 'lat' in msg:
            dd = json.loads(msg)
            self.net_handler.get_edge_id(dd['lng'], dd['lat'], dd['zoom'])
            self.on_map_clicked.emit(dd['lat'], dd['lng'], dd['zoom'])


class FoliumDisplay(QWidget):
    geojson_path = ""

    def redraw_folium_map(self, ):
        self.folium_map = folium.Map(zoom_start=self.zoom_level, location=(self.lon, self.lat),
                                     tiles='cartodbdark_matter', min_zoom=14)
        self.folium_map = self.add_geojson(self.folium_map, self.geojson_path)

        self.webView.page().profile().clearHttpCache()

        # save map data to data object
        data = io.BytesIO()
        self.folium_map.save(data, close_file=False)
        self.webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        return data

    def __init__(self, geojson_path, net_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.folium_map = None
        self.lon = 50.83421264776447
        self.lat = 4.366035461425782
        self.zoom_level = 15

        self.closed_edges = set()
        self.geojson_path = geojson_path
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 2000, 2000
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.webView = QWebEngineView()  # start web engine
        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        page.on_map_clicked.connect(self.map_clicked)
        self.webView.setPage(page)

        self.redraw_folium_map()
        layout.addWidget(self.webView)

    @Slot(float, float, int)
    def map_clicked(self, lon, lat, zoom_level):
        self.lon = lon
        self.lat = lat
        self.zoom_level = zoom_level

    def get_edge_color(self, feature):
        edge_id = feature['properties']['id']
        if edge_id not in self.closed_edges:
            return "#1a73e8"
        return "#D3D3D3"

    def add_geojson(self, map, fname):
        with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        popup = folium.GeoJsonPopup(fields=["id", "name"])
        elem = folium.GeoJson(data,
                              highlight_function=lambda feature: {"color": "#00FFF7"},
                              tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
                                  fields=['id', 'name'],
                                  aliases=['Edge ID:', 'Name:'],
                              ),
                              popup=popup,
                              popup_keep_highlighted=True,
                              style_function=lambda feature: {
                                  "color": self.get_edge_color(feature),
                                  "weight": 4 if feature['properties']['id'] not in self.closed_edges else 6
                              }
                              )
        # folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron').add_to(map)
        elem.add_to(map)
        my_js = f"""{elem.get_name()}.on("click",
                                 function (e) {{
                                    var data = e.latlng;
                                    data.zoom = {map.get_name()}.getZoom()
                                    var data_str = `{{"coordinates": ${{JSON.stringify(data)}}}}`;
                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                                    }});"""

        e = Element(my_js)
        html = elem.get_root()
        html.script.get_root().render()
        # Insert new element or custom JS
        html.script._children[e.get_name()] = e
        return map


Basically, when I want to refresh the map (When I adde some features in closed_edges set), I invoke the method redraw_folium_map() from a button's slot. But, nothing happens, despite the folium.GeoJson(..) is correctly invoked, and the method self.get_edge_color() works properly.
I suspect that the web page is not refreshed at all (I tried the various reload methods)

Update: I managed to refresh the page but apparently its not there the problem. I first save to HTML file the content of folium using the method save("page.html"), then reload the content of the web page from file. BUT, the reloaded file is not correct (some elements should be highlighted in the map in the QT app). Instead, if I open the saved html file in safari, everything is fine and the highlighted parts of the geojson are there. Thus reloading using self.window.webView.triggerPageAction(QWebEnginePage.ReloadAndBypassCache) does not solve the issue

Post a [mre] with a sample data file and debugging details.
